# Соединить 3 MySql запроса в 1

Tags: запрос, mysql

Нужно всё сделать **ОДНИМ** запросом. Помогите :)

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
while($data1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
 $id = $data1['id']; // определяем id пользователя

 // открываем таблицу материалов пользователя по id
 $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM `ents` WHERE `efrom_id` = '$id'");
 while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
  ...
 }
 // открываем таблицу вопросов пользователя по id
 $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM `questions` WHERE `qfrom_id` = '$id'");
 while($data3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)) {
  ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $query_ents = mysql_query('
    SELECT * 
    FROM `ents`
    JOIN `users` ON users.id = ents.efrom_id
    WHERE `users.login` = "' . $login . '"'
 );

 $query_questions = mysql_query('
    SELECT * 
    FROM `questions`
    JOIN `users` ON users.id=equestions.qfrom_id
    WHERE `users.login` = "' . $login . '"'
 );

 // Вывод ents
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_ents)) {
  ...
 }

 // Вывод questions
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_questions)) {
  ...
 }
```

Если одним запросом, то [[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) прав, необходимо использовать оператор UNION:

```
 $query = mysql_query('
   (SELECT \'questions\' tbl, users.id, users.login, questions.qname
   FROM `questions`
   JOIN `users` ON users.id=questions.qfrom_id
   WHERE users.login = "' . $login . '")

   UNION ALL

   (SELECT \'ents\' tbl, users.id, users.login, ents.ename
   FROM `ents`
   JOIN `users` ON users.id = ents.efrom_id
   WHERE users.login = "' . $login . '")'
 );

 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

   if ($data['tbl'] == 'questions') {
    ...
   }

   if ($data['tbl'] == 'ents') {
    ...
   }

 }
```

Если требуется декартово произведение, то опускаем "LEFT" и получаем оператор "JOIN". (Примечание: операторы "INNER JOIN" и "JOIN" в MySQL эквивалентны).

Навскидку, предлагаю ознакомиться с материалом по использованию в запросе оператора "JOIN", диаграмма Венна прилагается:

[Объяснение SQL объединений JOIN/INNER/OUTER](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html)

И конечно верно замечание [[@kuptsov](/users/6924/kuptsov)](/users/6924/kuptsov) про "*". Явное обозначение выводимых полей при обращении к нескольким сущностям, производится так:

```
SELECT user.id, users.name, questions.title...
```

Если поля в сущностях совпадают, то необходимо использовать алиасы, а именно:

```
SELECT user.id, users.name, questions.name AS `questions_name`...
```

Comment: @romeo, а как узнать например, когда LEFT JOIN, а когда right?

Comment: @ModaL Я исправил ответ, т.к. Вам необходимо выводить данные опираясь на две сущности (если я не ошибаюсь), а не на одну, как было в моём ответе ранее. Так что, @Yura Ivanov, был прав.

Что касается не декартовых (внешних) соединений:

К примеру, если мы объединяем две сущности Users и Questions, то оператор LEFT JOIN позволит вывести всех пользователей независимо от того, есть ли связанные с ним вопросы в сущности Questions (ещё проще: этот пользователь не задавал не единого вопроса). С оператором RIHGT JOIN всё в точности асимметрично.

На примере, это наглядней (ссылку приводил выше).

Comment: @romeo, вооо! Все работает! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`, ents, questions
WHERE
users.login=$login
and ents.efrom_id=users.id
and questions.qfrom_id=users.id
```

Comment: будет декартово произведение ets на questions.

Comment: [Смотрим](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31298/6) ваш запрос первый.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, как понять "Декартово"?

Comment: [Декартово произведение](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Декартово_произведение)
Когда два множества перемножаются получаются все возможные комбинации из обоих.
(1,2,3,4,5)x(101,102,103)=((1,101),(1,102),(1,103),(2,101),(2,102),(2,103)....(5,101),(5,102),(5,103)).
Т.е. если у вас в ents будет 10 записей для этого логина, а в questions 20, то запрос вам вернет 200 строк, в которых будут все возможные комбинации.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про оператор JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM users a INNER JOIN ents b ON a.id = b.efrom_id INNER JOIN questions c ON a.id = c.qfrom_id
```

Это пример запроса, его лучше модифицировать в зависимости от задачи выборки.
Ну и плюс - не советую выбирать данные по *, лучше все же прописывать что именно нужно выбрать, в данном случае - пользуясь алиасами таблиц,
это просто:

```
SELECT a.id, b.some_var, c.another FROM ...
```

Comment: [Смотрим](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31298/6) ваш запрос второй.

Comment: Что вы хотите этим показать?

Comment: что вы получили декартово произведение этим запросом. как и другие отвечающие. т.е. записей будет столько сколько записей в ents помноженное на количество записей в questions. будет и там и там по 10, ваш запрос вернет 100 записей.

Comment: Я привел пример использования JOIN'a, не вдаваясь в структуру данных.  
Полагаю что это лучше, чем подать человеку готовый вариант решения.  
Пусть он сам разберется, чтобы и в дальнейшем мог использовать приобретенный опыт.

Comment: @kuptsov это опыт составления неверного запроса. дальше начнутся distinct'ы, манипуляции с дублями в php и так далее. Какой смысл давать заведомо неверный ответ, не вдаваясь в структуру данных?

Comment: Не могу с Вами согласиться. Ответ верный - изучать JOIN. При этом в ответе написано - запрос модифицировать в зависимости от задачи.

Comment: вы бы еще написали "изучать sql" или "изучать теорию множеств". тоже верный ответ. только запрос либо модифицируйте в зависимости от задачи, либо уберите. 

он неверный, даже я бы сказал вредный. судя по тому, что у других отвечающих аналогичные запросы получились, никому не важно как и что работает зато много слов про то, что надо учить.

Comment: не надо профанаций. Я направил его мысль в нужное русло, достаточно узкое, а не "изучать sql". Что и как работает - нужно понимать самому, а не получать готовые решения на блюдечке.

Answer (score 0):

У вас разнородные данные в ents и questions, соответственно лучше сделать два запроса - по ents'ам и по questions'ам отдельно. Но если хочется одним запросом, чтоб был один цикл, то типа такого:

```
select u.id as user_id, u.login as user_login, 'ents' as info_type, e.ename as name
from users u
 join ents e ON u.id = e.efrom_id 
union all
select u.id, u.login, 'questions', q.qname
from users u
 join questions q ON u.id = q.qfrom_id
order by user_login, info_type;
```

соответственно в цикле у вас будет if с проверкой на info_type - что обрабатываем ents'ы или questions'ы.