# Добавить +1 запрос к 2-м другим SQL

Tags: php, sql

Есть 1 запрос, на получение информации с таблицы **tasks**:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `vk_id` != '$user_vk_id' AND $tsort AND `id` NOT IN ($tasks_done) AND `success` = '0' AND `del` = '0' ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 15");
```

Есть 2 других запроса, на получение списка пользователей, которые выполнили задание. Тут сразу 2 запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `type` = 'task' AND `message` LIKE '%''act'' => ''executed''%' AND (`message` LIKE '%''id'' => $id)%' OR `message` LIKE '%''id'' => $id,%') ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Мне нужно сделать 3 запроса, то есть из таблицы tasks получить id($data['id']) и подставить его вот сюда:

```
'%''id'' => ТУТ ИД из tasks)
```

Вообщем все 3 запроса нужно сделать 1 запросом. Помогите, пожалуйста сделать это.. Никак не разберусь :(

Comment: @ololoshka Вы бы представили графически, что именно должно выводится.

И с чего Вы решили, что во втором Вашем примере два запроса - один запрос, одна сущность.

Comment: @romeo, имел ввиду что два запроса в 1 запросе :D. Мне просто нужно соединить три запроса. У вас есть примеры как это сделать с помощью INNER JOIN?

Comment: @ololoshka Связь между сущностями (таблицами) `tasks` и `notifications` осуществляется только между полями **tasks.id** и **notifications.message** или существует другая связь?

Comment: @romeo, Вы всё верно сказали :))

>> Связь между сущностями (таблицами) tasks и notifications осуществляется только между полями tasks.id и notifications.message

Comment: @ololoshka если поля (для вывода) у этих двух сущностей разные, что скорее, то кроме как через хранимые процедуры в один запрос не получится сделать.

Comment: @romeo, просто скажите, как с помощью inner join соединить все 3 запроса? А то иначе сайт долго грузится, когда 3 раза mysql_query() пишешь

Comment: Нарисуйте примеры ваших таблиц с 2-3 строками. По ним будет проще ориентироваться, и помочь станет легче.

Comment: @korwru, попробую так. Есть таблица tasks, notifications и users. Таблица tasks содержит список заданий, таблица notifications информацию о том, кто выполнил это задание. В notifications есть поле message, которое хранит: array('id' => 'ИД ЗАДАНИЯ') и поле from, там хранится ид того, кто выполнил задание. Вот нужно одним запросом сделать следующее: получить список заданий(таблица tasks), получить тех, кто выполнил задание(поиск с помощью LIKE %'id' => 'ИД ЗАДАНИЯ'%) и аватар пользователя, который выполнил это задание(айди юзера в таблице tasks, поле from)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в этом направлении двигаться. Оператор CONCAT, возможно можно заменить на что-то иное.

```
SELECT *
   FROM `notifications`
   JOIN `tasks` ON notifications.message LIKE CONCAT('%', tasks.id, '%')
   WHERE 1
```

Если есть возможность поиска только конца строки, то лучше сделать именно так

```
CONCAT(tasks.id, '%')
```

, ибо в варианте '%var%' индекс не используется. Во втором случае, необходимо воспользоваться специальным решением для поиска MySQL - полнотекстовым (FULLTEXT) индексом и оператором MATCH (примечание: если конечно используете MyISAM движок).

[Поиск: FULLTEXT или LIKE?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/25646/)

В вашем случае, видимо LIKE предпочтительнее.

Если в одном запросе требуется вывести содержимое ещё и сущности `tasks`, то воспользуйтесь оператором **UNION** (внимание: в этом случае, количество столбцов должно совпадать. Вместо *****, прописываем каждый вручную). Вот пример моего ответа:

[Соединить 3 MySql запроса в 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/178068/query-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-3-mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-1)

Если остались вопросы, то пожалуйста, смоделируйте структуру (можно не всю) таблиц с ограниченным набором данных, которые участвуют в запросе вот [**здесь**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31298/6) (поскольку там уже размещён пример, Вам будет проще)

**P.S.** С наступающим!

Comment: Кстати, @romeo, а разве нельзя так: LIKE '%texttasks.id%'? Ну всмысле склеивание tasks.id

Comment: @ModaL Я пробовал - не вышло, т.к. это не текст, а SQL-сущность (ссылка на столбец id в таблице tasks), потому указал "...возможно можно заменить на что-то иное". Я не припомню, чтобы в своей практике сталкивался с таким запросом, поэтому, возможно, можно обойтись и без оператора CONCAT.

Comment: @ModaL Вы с @ololoshka в паре чтоль работает, а то синтаксис запросов больно Ваш похож:):

[Добавить ещё одну строку в INNER JOIN mysql][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/179173/inner-join-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-inner-join-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что тут не все в порядке  со структурой данных.